# Стоит ли разбивать большой массив байтов на части при передаче через NetWorkStream?

Tags: c#

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке. Имеются различные файлы, которые я передаю по сети через класс NetWorkStream. Файлы эти по объему различаются от сильно маленьких до относительно больших. Вопрос состоит в следующем: стоит ли записывать массив байтов файла в поток по частям(и считывать соответственно тоже) или можно сразу запихнуть в поток весь массив, а на другой стороне сразу все считать. Хотелось бы узнать за и против и, желательно, пояснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть исходники `NetworkStream`, то видно, что метод `Write` вызывает:

```
streamSocket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);
```

который в итоге вызывает:

```
UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.send(this.m_Handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ptr + offset, size, socketFlags);
```

Этот метод является экспортируемым нативным WinAPI методом: `ws2_32.dll` / `send`

Как можно видеть, .NET не пытается разбивать входной массив на меньшие куски, он делегерует это все низкоуровневому API.

Проблема может быть в том, что WinAPI функция `send` копирует ваши данные в объект ядра. Если вы отправите 1 Гб данных за 1 вызов `Write`, это повлечет за собой выделение 1 Гб памяти внутри ядра Windows. Если памяти в вас не очень много, это может создать проблемы.

Это поведение может различатся на других ОС.

Вопрос про эксперименты с функцией `send` и большым буффером на англоязычном стековервлоф: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785626/what-is-the-size-of-a-socket-send-buffer-in-windows

Comment: То, есть, если я буду записывать в поток, например, по 64кб, то памяти оно съест только 64кб?

Comment: Да. Оно возможно не всегда выделяет память, я деталей не знаю, но лучше самому разбивать на части

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую на больших файлах