# Можно ли одновременно записывать данные в NetWorkStream?

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой(пока что в теории).

Что будет, если попробовать одновременно записать данные в нетворкстрим? Не перемешаются ли данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, писать в один и тот же NetworkStream из разных потоков небезопасно.

`NetworkStream` вызывает `Socket.Send`. `Socket.Send` вызывает нативный `send` из `WS32.dll`.

[В документации к `send` сказано](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The order of calls made to send is also the order in which the buffers are transmitted to the transport layer. send should not be called on the same stream-oriented socket concurrently from different threads, because some Winsock providers may split a large send request into multiple transmissions, and this may lead to unintended data interleaving from multiple concurrent send requests on the same stream-oriented socket.

Т.е. send может разбить один вызов на несколько передач, и куски одновременно переданных буферов будут отправлены вперемешку друг с другом.

Кроме того,  send может взять и отправить только начала буфера (он возвращает количество отправленных байт,  которое может быть меньше заброшенного),  и вы получите фрагментацию и перемешивание разных сообщений из-за необходимости дослать неотправленное.

> Note  When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as send, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another blocking Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing blocking Winsock call on the same thread will lead to undefined behavior, and must never be attempted by Winsock clients.

Особенности вызова именно синхронной передачи (не через BeginSend) могут привести к непредсказуемому поведению.

Comment: Да, все как-то запутано. Насколько я понял, под "Winsock providers" имеется ввиду это - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider Если так, то случай с LSP-перехватом трафика и разбивкой большого куска на мелкие маловероятный. Это используется файрволами и антивирусами.

Comment: @Zergatul да, я скорее имел ввиду что гарантий со стороны api никаких нет. Т.е. для коротких буферов и стандартных провайдеров работать скорее всего будет. Но никаких гарантий что заработает на соседней машине. И что не будет поломан в будущем каким-то обновлением стандартного антивируса.

Comment: Вы немного неправильно пишете, не `send` может разбить буфер на куски, а пользовательская dll, которая зарегистрирована в LSP.

Comment: @Zergatul да, поправлю чуть позже, просто с телефона не получается уточнить. Но даже при этом - это происходит "внутри send" с точки зрения вызывающего,  и обнаружить это напрямую никак нельзя.

Comment: Если посмотреть с другой стороны, такая пользовательская dll-ка вообще может "поламать" весь трафик, и отправлять мусор. Фактически не гарантируется даже отправка буфера в один поток :)

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkStream` пишет данные напрямую в сокет, он не разбирает переданный массив байт на куски. Ничего не должно перемешиваться. Детальней можете посмотреть мой ответ здесь: [Стоит ли разбивать большой массив байтов на части при передаче через NetWorkStream?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794997/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-networkstre/795010#795010)

Операционная система сама "разрулит" параллельный вызов `send`. Какой-то выполнится первым, какой-то вторым. Подробнее об этом здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981372/are-parallel-calls-to-send-recv-on-the-same-socket-valid

Хотя в общем случае это не верно, детали в ответе PashaPash

Comment: Да вот как раз-таки не совсем то же самое. Дело в том, что при вызове метода Write переданный массив пишется в потом не сразу, а постепенно. Проверено. Если на другом конце считывать данные из потока методом Read и подставить третьим аргументом длину записанного массива, то совсем не обязательно считается именно это чисто байт. Проверил уже. Из чего у меня возникло опасение, что если попробовать из двух потоков одновременно что-то записать в Networkstream, то, предположим, первый Write еще не успел дописать массив в поток, а второй уже начал, откуда может произойти перемешивание.

Comment: @ElRabbito Понятное дело пишется не все сразу, это разруливает операционная система на уровне TCP/IP пакетов. Вы передаете массив байт на запись, ОС копирует его к себе, и посылает по частям, насколько позволяет скорость соединения.

Comment: В винде сокеты - не потокобезопасны на синхронных операциях. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx:  Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another blocking Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing blocking Winsock call on the same thread will lead to undefined behavior, and must never be attempted by Winsock clients.

Comment: @Zergatul ок. но там еще есть приписка про ub при одновременной передаче двух больших буферов. т.е. сам send их не режет, но конкретный провайдер - может порезать.

Comment: И вообще send может взять и не отправить весь переданный ему буфер - и сообщения уйдут вперемешку из-за необходимости досылать неотправленное - это написано по второй ссылке в вашем ответе, 3-й абзац в принятом ответе.

Comment: @PashaPash да, действительно может быть такая проблема.

Comment: @Zergatul Проблема в том, что lock, как я понял запрещает сторонним потокам получать доступ к участку кода, пока этот участок не освободится. Так вот потоков у меня много, а мне нужно запрещать одновременную запись не для всех потоков, а только для тех, которые хотят записать что-то в один и тот же NetWorkStream

Comment: @ElRabbito Пишите `lock (networkStream) { netwrokStream.Write(...); }`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75803/discussion-on-answer-by-zergatul-------netwo).

Comment: @ElRabbito, предлагаю принять другой ответ, раз этот неверный.